# How to convert a string to an enum array(keycode[])

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert a string which coul contain keycodes separated with a comma',' (F1,F2,A,B...).

But when I'm writing this values in a text File, I get UnityEngine.KeyCode[] instead of the real value .

```
    private static ConfigSimulation UpdateConfigSimulation(string path, ConfigSimulation config)
{
    #region ReadConfig
    Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    content = ReadConfigFile(path);
    #endregion
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cont in content)
    {
        if (config.Keys.ContainsKey(cont.Key))
        {
            KeyCode[] Tab = new KeyCode[cont.Value.Split(',').Length];
            if (!cont.Value.Contains(',') || (cont.Value.Length == 0))
            {
                KeyCode MyStatus = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), cont.Value, true);
                Tab[0] = MyStatus;
            }
            else if (cont.Value.Contains(','))
            {
                string[] Splits = cont.Value.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < Splits.Length; i++)
                {
                    KeyCode MyStatus = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), Splits[i], true);
                    Tab[i] = MyStatus;
                }
            }
            config.Keys[cont.Key] = Tab;
        }
    }
    return (config);
}
```

For the writing code:

```
        File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        file.WriteLine("###keys");
        foreach (var kvp in config.Keys)
        {
            file.WriteLine(kvp.Key + '=' + kvp.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete code example? what exactly is not working?

Comment: The code  browses a text file and if the values ​​correspond to keys, it does this processing.
I will add the writing code

Comment: rather add how and where it is called ... including the types for all variables

Comment: I hope that's more clear now

Comment: what is `config.Keys`? and what is `cont`?

Comment: ConfigSimulation is a class that contient 3 dictionnary ,one of them is keys which is a <string,keycode[] > dictionnary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.Keys` is of type `Dictionary<string, KeyCode[]>` so when you do

```
foreach (var kvp in config.Keys)
{
    file.WriteLine(kvp.Key + '=' + kvp.Value);
}
```

`kvp.Value` is of type `KeyCode[]` so it's implicitely called `ToString()` returns `"KeyCode[]"`. There is no implicit method that prints out all values comma separated.

---

Convert the array to a comma separated string using [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join) like

```
foreach (var kvp in config.Keys)
{
    file.WriteLine(kvp.Key + '=' + string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
}
```

Comment: public class ConfigSimulation : MonoBehaviour {

        public Dictionary<string, KeyCode[]> Keys { get;  } = new Dictionary<string, KeyCode[]>();
}

Comment: I don't know ... where (which line, which variable) do you get it?